# Frieza's whopping power level in the Real 4-D

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

In a cinematic attraction at Universal Studios Japan, [Dragon Ball Z: The Real 4-D](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_The_Real_4-D), Frieza has shown to have a power level of 5.3 Billion. Does that count as true? AFAIK, during Frieza Saga, 100% Final Form Frieza's power level is only around 120 Million according to [this list](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_power_levels). Is Toriyama completely ignoring the previous power level or just for advertising purposes?

Comment: Remember that Freeza did do alot of training after he was resurected, though i'm not sure what his power levels are in either his pre-gold and post-gold forms

Comment: I rewatch it on youtube and realized I missed something. A mysterious guy wished back Frieza with stronger power than Goku, that's why the power level is ridiculous. Ah silly me.

Comment: @HappyFace You should flesh that out and post it as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Considering it tells events that never happened in the series, (just as Goku, Vegeta, Piccolo and Krilin figthing Freezer together) , it means it is an official production (officially licensed) but non canon. So the answer is it counts as official but not as canon, it's not a figure which is part of the main storyline.